# Rewrite an even number as 2^a * b

Tags: c#, math, logic

I'm looking for an algoritm that takes an even number bigger than 2, and rewrite it as (2 to the power a) times b, with a and b being calculated by the algoritm and b being an odd number.

Comment: And what problem do you have?

Comment: You're looking or your professor is looking?  Stack Overflow is not a "do my homework for me" site.

Comment: @DavidL it's just a small part of an assignment, i thought it was an interesting question but i'll delete it if no one can help me.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin well i can't figure out an algorithm that gives the above, especially the fact b always has to be an odd number

Comment: In the future all professors will have to check SO periodically to see if their students are cheating ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `x` is the input number, divide `x` by two. If the new number is even, repeat the process, until the outcome is odd. This odd number is `b` in your formula, while `a` is the number of iterations you just performed.

Now that you have an idea on the algorithm, try coding it. StackOverflow will not do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, i was not looking for the code, i was looking for the reasoning you just gave me.